# An edge turned pinkish but it's not seam after putting subdivision surface modifier

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

I am making the Blender Guru donuts. I noticed this edge of this reddish color after putting subdivision surface on the donuts icing. It's not seam cause I can't remove it with U -> Clear seam.

[image: the reddish edge]
What is it and how do I remove it?

Comment: Ok, now I noticed that the red edge is present in the tutorial itself, but what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's the *Crease*, select this edge loop, open the *N panel > Item > Edge Data* and bring back the *Crease* to zero, or select, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and drag. It is used to sharp angles.

Comment: Will keeping it be right for uv unwrapping?

Comment: yes no problem, also, if you want a sharp edge but don't want to use crease, create additional edges close to the one you want to sharp

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks mate.